# Hadoop WordCount MapReduce: Getting invalid argument error for setInputFormatClass

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a wordcount program but I am getting error for below code

```
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

> Error:- "The method setInputFormatClass(Class)
>   in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Class)"

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem (without seeing all of your code) is that you've mixed the two mapreduce APIs, the `mapred` and `mapreduce`.

Check the `imports` for the two classes. I'm guessing yours probably look like:

`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat`

When it should be:

`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat`

Comment: Good to hear. Please accept the answer if its correct.